# how to avoid repeated codes in R

Tags: r

I am creating 2 data frames and merging them. I have created duplicate codes below, Since I am new in R programming I want the same results without creating repeated codes.

```
     category sex day   flag     value       mean        Standard deviation
1        FC   F   -1          a     17.2     17.01333             0.9463212
2        FC   F   -1          a     17.0     17.01333             0.9463212
3        FC   F   -1          a     18.7    17.01333              0.9463212
4        FC   F   -1          a     17.1    17.01333             0.9463212
5        FC   F   -1          a     17.2    17.01333             0.9463212
6        FC   F   -1          a     17.2    17.01333             0.9463212
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(doBy)
library(tidyverse)
data <- read.csv("users/study.csv")
print(data)

new_table <- select(data, category, sex, day, flag,value)
target1 <- "a"
target2<-"b"

#Repeated Codes
filtered1<-filter(new_table, sex=="F", category=="FC",flag %in% target1,day==-1)
filtered1
filtered2<-filter(new_table, sex=="F", category=="FC",flag %in% target2,day==-1)
filtered2

result1<-filtered1 %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(value),
         `Standard deviation` = sd(value))
result2<-filtered2 %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(value),
         `Standard deviation` = sd(value))

#Merging the dataframes
dataframe<-do.call("rbind", list(result1,result2))
dataframe
```

Comment: Do the columns `Sex` & `FC` have values other than `F` and `FC` respectively?

Comment: yes it has values other than F and FC, I want to filter each values from this column and take the results. But since FC has more values, how it should be done without hard coding the values while filtering

Comment: and you may want these calculations for each of such value combinations?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Yes, I have to filter in multiple combinations. for example in "Category" and "Flag"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want either of these two

```
new_table %>%
  group_by(sex, category, flag, day) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(value),
         standardDeviation = sd(value))
```

or

```
new_table %>%
  group_by(sex, category, flag, day) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value),
         standardDeviation = sd(value))
```

Comment: But I have to filter in multiple combinations. for example in "Category" and "Flag"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `group_by()`

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- new_table %>%
  subset(sex=="F" & category=="FC" & day==-1) %>%
  group_by(flag) %>%
  mutate(mean=mean(value),
         `Standard deviation` = sd(value))
```

Comment: I think you should try `new_table %>% 
  filter(day==-1) %>% 
  group_by(sex, category, flag) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value),
         SD = sd(value))`

Comment: Roman is right ! If you want the mean and sd for every combinations you should use his answer.