# mean and standard deviations for multiple combinations of filter in R programming

Tags: r

I have data where I want to filter in multiple combinations in the below columns and take the mean and standard deviation. Each corresponding combination of the mean and SD should come in the dataframe using R. As per the current filtration the code does not give me mean and standard deviation,  I know that I am missing something, looking for the solution since I am new in R programming

Combinations should be :
Category: FC
Sex: M
Flag: a

and

Category: WC
Sex: F
Flag: b

etc...

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(doBy)
library(tidyverse)
data <- read.csv("users/report.csv")


new_table <- select(data, category, sex, day, flag,value)

filtered_category <- c(category="FC",category="WC")
filtered_day<- c(day=-1, day=2)
filtered_sex <- c(sex="M", sex="F")
setcd_flag <- c(flag="e",flag="f",flag="g",flag="h",flag="i")



filtered1<-filter(new_table, sex%in%filtered_sex,  category%in% filtered_category,flag %in% filtered_flag,fwdy %in% filtered_fwdy)
filtered1

result1<-filtered1 %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(fwstresn),
         `Standard deviation` = sd(fwstresn))

result1
```

Current result:

```
category value day    sex   flag  Mean   SD
WC  46.6    39  M      a     20.5   2.8
WC  49.4    74  M      a     20.5   2.8
WC  50.2    70  F      a     19.5   1.8
WC  45.6    34  F      a     19.5   1.8
WC  50.2    67  F      a     19.5   1.8
WC  49.7    42  M      b     40.0   2.9
FC  22.6    102 M      b     40.0   2.9
FC  21.5    112 M      b     40.0   2.9
WC  49.6    63  M      b     40.0   2.9
WC  47.7    32  M      c     20.5   3.5
FC  16      105 M      c     20.5   3.5
WC  43.7    9   M      c     20.5   3.5
```

dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(
 category=c("WC","WC","WC","WC","WC","WC","WC","WC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC","FC"),
 sex=c("M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F"),
 flag=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
value=c(33.4,28.7,28.7,33.8,34.1,33.8,35.4,2.5,25.6,22,22,24.3,24,24.3,23.4,29.3,23.4,29.3,25.5,30.2,30.2,27.4,27.4,24)
```

Desired output:

```
category    value   day sex flag    Mean    Standard
WC  33.4    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  28.7    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  28.7    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  33.8    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  34.1    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  33.8    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  35.4    -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
WC  2.5     -1  M   a   30.71   11.61
                        
FC  25.6    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  22      -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  22      -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  24.3    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  24      -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  24.3    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  23.4    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  29.3    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  23.4    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  29.3    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  25.5    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  30.2    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  30.2    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  27.4    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  27.4    -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
FC  24      -1  M   a   25.76   2.82
```

Comment: Someone already asked this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071686/how-to-get-mean-and-standard-deviation-for-multiple-combinations-of-filters-in-r. You need to provide your starting dataframe and desired output in reproducible form for us to help you answer the question.

Comment: Not the same user, also the expected result is not provided in the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071686/how-to-get-mean-and-standard-deviation-for-multiple-combinations-of-filters-in-r

Comment: I have added the data frame and the desired output

Comment: same question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070409/how-to-avoid-repeated-codes-in-r/67070595#67070595)

Comment: @AnilGoyal in OP's defense, there's no indication that they're the same user, nor that they are aware of the post you linked to. Plus they seem to be absolutely new here. And they have responded to issues raised in the comments by amending the question. I don't think this needs to be closed (nor for that matter, downvoted).

Comment: Yes, but the same solution `new_table %>%   group_by(sex, category, flag, day) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(value),  standardDeviation = sd(value))` will work here too..

Comment: @Dunois, actually there are three same questions by three different users, that's raise a doubt.  However, close vote has been retracted.  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070409/how-to-avoid-repeated-codes-in-r/67070595#67070595) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071686/how-to-get-mean-and-standard-deviation-for-multiple-combinations-of-filters-in-r) please.

Comment: But None of the solutions are working as per desired output that I am looking for

Comment: Still seeking the correct solutions

Comment: I have added the Dataframe.

Comment: @Dunois, I have shared the desired data frame for your reference above

Answer (score 1):

Its challenging to test an answer because you have not provided the dataframe in easily reproducible form.  However, try this:

```
desired_output <- data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(category) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(c("value"), list(mean, sd))) %>% 
  dplyr::inner_join(data)
```

Comment: I am getting the error : Error: `x` and `y` must share the same src, set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow).

Comment: Apologies - I edited the code so you can try again